# How to do this calculation?

Tags: calculus

I have a function f(x) and I am required to calculate the following:

$$\frac{\Delta f}{f}$$

I have no clue on what I have to do? Would it be valid to do the derivative of f divided by f?

Comment: The meaning of the notation you wrote varies depending on the context. Specifically, $\Delta f$ is a shorthand for $f(y)-f(x)$ for some $x,y$ which are chosen beforehand. So, in order to assign a meaning to the expression $\frac{\Delta f}{f}(x)$ you ideally need the author explicitly specify a function $h(x)$ and say out loud that $$\frac{\Delta f}{f}(x)=\frac{f(x+h(x))-f(x)}{f(x)}$$ Needless to say, the quantity $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ hardly ever coincides with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably calculate ${(f(x+1)-f(x))}/f(x)$. The symbol $\Delta$ generally defaults to a difference of 1 in the argument. $f(x+h)-f(x)$ would be $\Delta_h f$. See e.g.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

And, no, this is not $f'(x)/f(x)$ in general.